# Link creation still possible with magnet : false

Tags: jointjs

I'm changing the elements magnet value this way:

```
currentNode.attr("image/magnet","false");
```

However, even though the cursor changes to a hand instead of the cross used for link creation, I still can create links from that element.
It seems that once the magnet value has been set to true for an element image it somehow stays that way forever.

This is an unexpected behavior indeed...

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Try `currentNode.attr("image/magnet","passive");` or `currentNode.attr("image/magnet","");`.  Please see `validateMagnet` paper option at http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper.

Comment: Thanks! it works when using the first statement ;)

Comment: Note that there is actually a difference between those 2 statements. The first disables link creation from the magnet, but allows links still to be connected to this magnet. The other disables both.

Comment: cool thanks for the info ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when using

```
currentNode.attr("image/magnet","");
```

instead of

```
currentNode.attr("image/magnet","false");
```